# Dump import stops and no error message

Tags: database, oracle, import, dump

I'm importing a .dmp file to an Oracle DB from a remote desktop with this command (using Putty) :

```
imp system/xxxxx@RDJD1 file=livraison_1.dmp fromuser=bob_rp touser=bob_rp log=livraison_1.log
```

The import runs but get stuck several minutes later. I thought that maybe it's because a timeout, so in the Connection configuration on Putty I added a timer to send null packets to keep the session active.
But the import get stuck exactly on the same table (which is not a huge table).

Here what look like my terminal output at the end (no error message):

```
. . Importing table "C_TABLE16" 900789 rows
. . Importing table "C_TABLE17" 127 rows
. . Importing table "C_TABLE18"
```

(Also, I think it's related : after the failed import, when I close my terminal and want to connect to sqlplus I get an error message :

```
ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed.
```

And if I retry several minutes later, then I can connect to sqlplus without error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to talk to your DBA about the archive log settings. The import is waiting for the archiver error to be cleared, and new connections won't be allowed until that happens too. If you wait long enough the import should resume on its own - at the same time, you'll be able to connect through SQL*Plus. They are both affected by the same issue, but the effect is different because `imp` already has a connection/session, and SQL*Plus is asking for a new one.

Essentially you're writing data to the tables and causing redo log switches faster than those log files can be swapped and archived. There may not be enough redo groups, or the logs are too small, or there's a storage layer issue, or the are the archived logs is too small to hold them before they are backed up and removed.

If the DBA investigates and changes the settings it might help it go through more smoothly. At the moment it's either just catching up after a while, or the DBA is getting an alert and manually clearing a problem.

(Incidentally, you might find the [feedback parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#sthref2172) helpful to monitor progress; wouldn't avoid this problem but you might see a few dots before it stalls, and then you'll see them resume when the error clears - rather than waiting for the whole table to complete).

Comment: Thank you, I sent a message to my DBA. So if he just increases the archiver error space, it should resolve the problem right ?

Comment: There are few things they could look at, they will probably have a preference about the best way to prevent the problem in your environment. They will recognise the error and know what it means. Or they may tell you to just be patient if it's clearing itself after a while, of course, in which case the feedback dots might be useful.

Comment: You can [read more about redo logs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/physical.htm#CNCPT11305) if you're interested.